# Permission denied (publickey) in GIT clone

Tags: git, ssh, gitlab

I am completely new in GIT and I am trying to clone a project from the gitlab by typing:

```
git clone ssh://gitlab@gitlab.symmetrics.de:504/path/to/project
```

But it says `Permission denied (publickey)`

What I have tried so far is:

1. Generate a new SSH key and add it to my GitLab account.
2. Add a config file into my .ssh folder (IdentityFile is absolutely correct).
3. I added the identity with `ssh-add id_rsa`.

But nothing worked and it still says that permission is denied because of the publickey.

I am a little confused because of the `gitlab@gitlab.symmetrics.de`, because it's not the same as `git@gitlab.com`.

When i try `ssh -T git@gitlab.com` it prints a welcome message and when I try to `ssh -T gitlab@gilab.symmetrics.de` it says that `Resource is temporary unavailable`.

Besides that, I've tried to write `ssh -v gitlab@gitlab.symmetrics.de` and checked the IP address. Then tried to ping to the server and it pinged.

What is wrong? Thank you very much for any help...

Comment: Get your ssh address and use `git clone git@gitlab.test.in:3sky/jenkinsfiles/test.git`. It's look like You use wrong url.

Comment: If the URL would be wrong, ssh would say that he can't resolve the hostname, no?

Comment: URL was bed word :) You have ssh address which look like `git@gitlab.test.in:3sky/jenkinsfiles/test.git` and http adress which look like that `https://gitlab.test.in/gitlab/3sky/jenkinsfiles/test.git`

Comment: So do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Checkout project permission, and be sure that You use proper `git` user. And that's all, it should works.